# Integrating $ \int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}\,dx. $

Tags: integration

I need to compute
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}\,dx.
$$
Using the fact that $\frac{d(x^y)}{dy} = (\ln x)x^y$,

I can't get any clue.

Can someone give me a tip on how to better approach solving these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use Feynman's integration under the integral sign where the parameter is :

$$
\mathcal I(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Thnks~~~~~ !!!  Could you please give me some tips about how to solve these kinds of tricky definite integrals?

Comment: @user197137 Practice.

Comment: @user201168, remember what i said last time.

Comment: @abel What did you say?

Comment: @user201168, that let no one teach you math.

Comment: @abel Ah! I remember quiet well, it's just that I thought it was McB who wrote that. ;-)

Comment: @user201168, this is from someone who teaches math for a living!

Comment: @abel Thanks, I really appreciate that. If you have more advice then please send it to me via my email (see my profile).

Answer (score 3):

Hint. You are on the right track, you can write $$\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=\int_{0}^{1}x^y dy$$ and then reverse the integration order.

Obtaining
$$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx= \int_0^1\frac{1}{y+1}dy=\ln2$$

Comment: Thnks~~~~~ !!! Could you please give me some tips about how to solve these kinds of tricky definite integrals?

Comment: unbelievably nice! +1

Answer (score 0):

The method of [Differentiation Under the Integral Sign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWA-1rsSSh4) consists in differentiating $I(a)$ with respect to $a$ and then integrate it back with respect to $x$

Spoiler:

> $$\begin{align}I(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a -1 }{\ln x} dx &\Rightarrow I'(a) =  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a\ln x }{\ln x} dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^a dx \\&\Rightarrow I(a) = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\Bigg|_{0}^{1}\end{align}$$

and then take $a = 1$.